# iphone how to determine SDK used to build an app

Tags: iphone, ipad, xamarin.ios

I am getting an error when submitting to iTunes, "Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK". I have xcode_3.2.4_and_ios_sdk_4.1 installed. Xcode 4 is out, so I should be still good.

How can I determine what version was used if I only have the MyApp.app file?
Ian

I do have this in the build output, but 4.1 should be ok???

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 -arch armv6 -gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=3.2 -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.1.sdk -c /var/folders/0I/0IVt0CAJH24x9KMyLBKAAk+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp43533fea.tmp/MonoTouch.UICatalog.dll.s -o /var/folders/0I/0IVt0CAJH24x9KMyLBKAAk+++TI/-Tmp-/tmp43533fea.tmp/MonoTouch.UICatalog.dll.o
```

Comment: What do you mean by you have only .app file? You don't have access to the developer who created it? ;)

Comment: I have that, but I use MonoTouch, that does not get me deep enough into what was used internally.

Comment: No matter what the answer is, you should *always* build against the latest SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must install Xcode 3.2.6 with iOS SDK 4.3.1 for apple to accept the upload.

Comment: That's the wierdness. I have 4.3.1 installed now, but still I get the same message from Apple. "Apple is not currently accepting applications built with this version of the SDK".